# TFS 2018 Call for add Administrator's API to Project Returns 404 @tfs

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

TFS 2018 Call for add Administrator's API to Project Returns 404:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to [list Group Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/group%20entitlements/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1). Unfortunately, this api only supports VSTS, not support on-premises TFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean adding, then it should be a `POST` request, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/group%20entitlements/add?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for more details. On the other hand, if you want to `GET`, you should [specify the `groupId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/group%20entitlements/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1#examples).